# AWS-RunPowershell CLI won't accept curly brackets for Windows command

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I'm trying to run:

```
aws ssm --region us-east-1 send-command --instance-ids "i-008d4b86c352c2bcf" --document-name "AWS-RunPowerShellScript" \
--parameters 'commands="yApp = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq `App I do not want`}" , `Start-Sleep 600` ,  `$MyApp.Uninstall()`'
```

AWS CLI does not like the Curly Brackets and I can not find a way to run this without them or with them escaped.

I tried several ways to escape the brackets or to use other brackets, nothing seems to work.

Comment: What error message do you receive?

Comment: It puts a ^ under the A in 'App I do not want'

Comment: Rather than using backticks as quotes, I wonder if you can escape a quote with backtick+quote: `"